# How to install foreign_relay package?

Tags: ros, ros-lunar, multi-robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to install wifi_comm (http://wiki.ros.org/wifi_comm) in ROS Lunar Desktop-Full distribution and I need to install foreign_relay (http://wiki.ros.org/foreign_relay). Someone knows how do it?

Thank for the help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/268785/how-to-install-foreign_relay-package?/) by [Mirco](https://answers.ros.org/users/31476/mirco/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ruben Alves](https://answers.ros.org/users/25452/ruben-alves/) on 2017-10-28**:
What you want is have then manually installed on the `/opt/ros/lunar/` folder, yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you're happy to compile from source, `git clone https://github.com/willowgarage/multimaster_experimental.git` into the `/src` of a catkin workspace.

---

Originally posted by [Will Chamberlain](https://answers.ros.org/users/21723/will-chamberlain/) with karma: 56 on 2018-01-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0